# Retrieving DOM textnode position

Tags: dom, textnode

Is it possible to retrieve the geometric position (i.e. top/left offsets from either the parent element, the page, etc) of a text node?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not directly. TextNode does not have the originally-IE offset* (and similar) extensions for measuring on-viewport positioning.

On IE only, you could create a TextRange object, laboriously attempt to align it with the bounds of the TextNode, then measure the boundingLeft/boundingTop of the TextRange, and add it to the position of the parent element (obtained by the usual means). However this is a bunch of work for a potentially-wobbly single-browser solution.

Another approach you might be able to get away with would be wrapping the text in a span element (either in the document, or dynamically and/or temporarily by script), and using the span to measure positioning, assuming it's not picking up any additional styles that may affect the position. Note however that a wrapped span may not give the expected right/bottom values; depending on what you want to do with it, you might end up wrapping the first and last character or some other arrangement.

In summary: urgh, nothing good.

Comment: Used your idea - thanks for the insight! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990350/jquery-get-text-currently-shown-ie-not-just-visible/6990382#6990382

Comment: shame but wrapping in a span is modifying the page so no use to me

Answer (score 12):

**Today you can** via [`Range.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/getBoundingClientRect).

```js
// Get your text node
const el = document.querySelector('strong')
const textNode = el.firstChild;

// Get coordinates via Range
const range = document.createRange();
range.selectNode(textNode);
const coordinates = range.getBoundingClientRect()

console.log(coordinates);
```

```css
/* Demo CSS, ignore, highlights box coordinates */ body{max-width:300px}strong{position:relative}strong,strong:before{border:solid 1px red}strong:before{content:'';position:absolute;right:100%;bottom:100%;width:100vw;height:100vh;pointer-events:none}
```

```html
The red lines will show you the coordinates bounding box of the <strong>selected textnode</strong>.
```

Comment: I gave you +1 for giving, for me the best answer here.  I have verified that this works in Chromium as well.  Looking at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/getBoundingClientRect, it looks pretty widely supported, thus IMO this should be the chosen answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Text node relative to viewport**

```js
function getBoundingClientRectText(textNode) {
  const range = document.createRange()
  range.selectNode(textNode)
  return range.getBoundingClientRect()
}
```

**Text node relative to an element**

```js
function getTextOffsetRelativeToElement(element, textNode) {
  const elementRect = element.getBoundingClientRect()
  const range = document.createRange()
  range.selectNode(textNode)
  const textRect = range.getBoundingClientRect()
  return {
    top: textRect.top - elementRect.top,
    left: textRect.left - elementRect.left
  }
}
```

**Character offset relative to text node's parent element**

```js
function getCharOffset(textNode, offset) {
  const parentRect = textNode.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect()
  const range = document.createRange()
  range.setStart(textNode, offset)
  range.setEnd(textNode, offset + 1)
  const charRect = range.getBoundingClientRect()
  return {
    top: charRect.top - parentRect.top,
    left: charRect.left - parentRect.left
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html) - it uses the offsetParent property to recursively figure out the offset.

I would always recommend jquery over rolling your own methods for browser-varying stuff like this. The [jquery CSS functions](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS) seem to have the methods you need!

Comment: Unfortunately, DOM text nodes do not seem to have offsetLeft/offsetTop properties. And jQuery doesn't handle text nodes nicely, too: I couldn't find out how to write a selector expression for them (nevermind that children() doesn't return text nodes).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any built-in, cross-browser way to do this.  I would
use jQuery with the Dimensions plugin: http://brandonaaron.net/docs/dimensions/

It is cross-browser and will give you height, width and x & y offsets, among others.

Answer (score -1):

These days there are ways. One way: getBoundingRectangle: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect

Comment: clientRects are not available for text nodes.