# scroll to text in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

For a Google Chrome plugin, I am trying to scroll to a DOM element containing a given string. However, after filtering a selector, I am a little bit lost in the DOM.

```
$('*', 'body')
    .andSelf()
    .contents()
    .filter(function(){                     
        return this.nodeType === 3;
    })
    .filter(function(){
        // Only match when contains given string anywhere in the text       

        if(this.nodeValue.indexOf(givenString != -1){
            //idArr.push(this.offsetLeft);

            var ele = $(this);
                       $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: ele.offset().top
                     }, 2000);                              
                return true;
            }

            return false;

    });
```

Whenever I try to get the top offset of `ele`, I get the top offset of the scrollbar in relation to the document instead. Any ideas? I thought it might be a scoping issues with my use of `$this` inside the filter, but `this` inside a filter should refer to the current DOM element.

EDIT:

by calling

`var ele=$(this.parentNode);`

I was able to get the element that contained the text node

Comment: Maybee this help for you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollIntoView

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var matches = $('body, body *').
        addBack().
        contents().
        filter(function(){                     
            return this.nodeType === 3;
        }).
        filter(function(){
        // Only match when contains given string anywhere in the text               
             if(this.nodeValue.indexOf(givenString) != -1)
               return true;
        }).first();
```

Basically the same filtering you had (I just added a missing parenthesis). This will give you the first (if any) textnode that matches your string. But since you can't get a textnodes position in the DOM directly (refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396649/retrieving-dom-textnode-position)) you may want to try a simple trick, wrapping it inside a span element and then retrieving the offset to scroll the page:

```
if(matches.length > 0){
    var offset = $(matches).wrap('<span>').parent().offset().top;
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: offset}, 'slow');
}
```

Fiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CXjgB/)

Answer (score 0):

```
el = $(":not(html, body, div, table, tbody, tr):contains('" + givenString + "')")
```

This will return the matched elements. Then you can scroll to the element